# paintcomponent repeats itself without any user interaction

Tags: java, loops, paintcomponent, repeat

I'm working on a project which uses paintcomponent.
The problem is that this paintcomponent method is executing itself repeatively without asking.
I discovered this problem by creating a counter that raises the method runs everytime and I printed this out. Now is see that the method repeats itself randomly.
The problem is that this makes message boxes etc execute multiple times and freeze.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You should post an [SSCCE](http://sccee.org) so we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: Is it possible you have `repaint()` in the actionlistener of the timer?

Answer (score 2):

`paintComponent` is a low-level method which can be called at any time at the discretion of the GUI engine. It is not a place to instantiate any message boxes or similar, but to use low-level 2D graphics calls to *paint your custom component*. Your use case may actually call for a different mechanism whereby to refresh your screen.

Comment: Indeed. One thing to be on your guard for in a paintComponent is to prevent that you trigger additional repaints from it. Opening a dialog will require a (partial) repaint, or else it won't ever appear on screen!